# Get some attributes with different class(es) using html agility pack

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack, selectnodes

I want to get some attributes with different class(es) using "html agility pack select node".

I could catch all of them one by one with "Html Node Collection" but Its not a pro work. any suggestion to do that ?

HTML code :

```
<span itemprop="tel">(021) 000000(300)</span>
<p class="mobile">93900000</p>
<p class="fax">660000</p>
<span itemprop="street-address">انقلاب - پژوهشگاه علوم و </span>
```

C# :

```
HtmlNodeCollection nodes =
doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//p[@class='Fax']");
```

Comment: There is no `a` element in your sample HTML. Which values exactly you are trying to get from this HTML?

Comment: Sorry there was a mistyping...

Comment: So, whats wrong with your current approach? Which results do you get now, and what do you want to get?

Comment: Speculation: You're selecting from the class 'Fax', but the class in the HTML is 'fax'. Is the selection case sensitive?

Comment: I try to get all the classes to a NodeCollection. I currently do in one by one. that means I write a HtmlNodeCollection for Class=fax and a separate NodeCollection for Class=mobile. Is there any way to get all the classes with different values ?